# why key error Recursion component in React

Tags: reactjs, recursion, key

i'm trying to recursion components but react key props is duplicate in root
when using uuid, is fine. i don't know reason, help me

```
// filterModal.jsx
<FilterGroupCollection
            parentFiltergroup={parentFiltergroup}
            setParentFilterGroup={setParentFilterGroup}
            name='a'
/>
```

```
{parentFiltergroup.groups?.map((group, idx) => (
          <FilterGroupCollection
            key={name}
            parentFiltergroup={group}
            setParentFilterGroup={setParentFilterGroup}
            name={`${name}-${idx + 1}`}
          />
        ))}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VD8Y.png)

Comment: change `key = {name}` to `key = {idx}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the same value for the key prop and that's why you are getting the key duplicate error in the console. Ideally you should use a unique key for each component, and that key could be a unique id that you get from each group. Something like this:

```
{parentFiltergroup.groups?.map((group, idx) => (
 <FilterGroupCollection
   key={group.id} //notice here the id that you should get from each group
   parentFiltergroup={group}
   setParentFilterGroup={setParentFilterGroup}
   name={`${name}-${idx + 1}`}
 />
))}
```

Alternatively, if you do not have any unique value inside each group, you can use the **idx** as key but this is not a good practice as explained by React:

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys